VSTO Word-Addin can't show publisher name on MS-Word
VSTO Word-Addin; I Already set publisher name and digitelly sign with digi-cert. when i sign with digi-cert than it is show the publisher name on when install the addin but it is can't show publiher name on MS-Word File -> Options -> Add-in and selction the addin then it's can't show publisher name.
can anyone plese help me out on this issue.
#Vsto #Word-Addin #Issue #Publisher #PublisherName #VSTO-C# #WordAddin
VSTO Word-Addin; I digitelly sign with digicert but it show on publiser name when install the addin. I need to show publisher name on MS-Word File -> Options -> Add-in and selction the addin
